# Installling Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a X99 Motherboard with Intel Xeon E5 Processor

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, system-installation, ubiquity

I assembled a Machinist X99 motherboard server machine with Intel Xeon E5 v3 2690 processor and by now I'm trying to set up a Ubuntu Server on it. I got Ubuntu Server ISO with YUMI bootable USB, but I cannot finish the process because in the last screen appears an error message about "ubiquity". My question is: what is this error about and how could I fix it to finish the booting process?

Comment: "*an error message about 'ubiquity'*" is a bit too vague to offer useful advice. Can you show us the complete, exact error message?